# Modelica connect equation

Tags: modelica

Can anyone tell me if i can model as below where model Main connects model A and model B. It gives error : 6 equations and 8 variables but how can connect such models.

```
model A
Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.RealInput ain1;
Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.RealInput ain2;
Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.RealInput ain3;
Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.RealInput ain4;
Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.RealOutput aout1;
Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.RealOutput aout2;
end A;

model B
Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.RealInput bin1;
Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.RealInput bin2;
end B;

model Main
Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.RealInput min1;
Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.RealInput min2;
Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.RealInput min3;
Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.RealInput min4;
A a;
B b;
equation
connect(a.ain1,min1);
connect(a.ain2,min2);
connect(a.ain3,min3);
connect(a.ain4,min4);
connect(a.aout1,b.bin1);
connect(a.aout2,b.bin2);
end Main;
```

Answer (score 1):

Right now, you have 6 equations (one per `connect` statement). However, you have 8 variables (one for each `RealInput` and each `RealOutput`). From a mathematical point of view, this means that your model is [under-determined](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Under-determined), because you have more variables than equations.

To solve this, you need to add two additional equations. Logically, the missing link seems to be how the two outputs of `A` are related to the inputs of `A`. For example, the following model (where I've added such a relation between the inputs and outputs of `A`) is fine:

```
model Main  
  model A
    Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.RealInput ain1;
    Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.RealInput ain2;
    Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.RealInput ain3;
    Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.RealInput ain4;
    Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.RealOutput aout1;
    Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.RealOutput aout2;
  equation
     aout1 = ain1 + ain2;
     aout2 = ain3 + ain4;
  end A;

  model B
    Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.RealInput bin1;
    Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.RealInput bin2;
  end B;  

  Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.RealInput min1;
  Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.RealInput min2;
  Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.RealInput min3;
  Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.RealInput min4;
  A a;
  B b;
equation
  connect(a.ain1,min1);
  connect(a.ain2,min2);
  connect(a.ain3,min3);
  connect(a.ain4,min4);
  connect(a.aout1,b.bin1);
  connect(a.aout2,b.bin2);
end Main;
```

Comment: Just to add one point to Florian's answer.  Your original `A` model was not legal Modelica.  Modelica requires that each individual component is balanced (as many equations as unknowns).  This allows tools to give more specific diagnostics.  I would have expected your Modelica compiler to have said something more like "Cannot instantiate 'a' in model 'Main' because the model 'A' is not properly balanced (2 unknowns, but 0 equations)."